# Detect file creation or deletion under given path using python and kqueue on FreeBSD

Tags: python, freebsd, kqueue

Given /certain/path/ on a FreeBSD system, I would like python to use kqueue to detect if any files are created or deleted anywhere under that path.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/) package which in turn uses kqueue on BSD (and inotify on Linux, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Accordint to Python's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html), kqueue/kevent are already supported (only on BSD, of course) "out of the box"...